# How to get the week start in this format '07-Feb-22' in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi there please help me .
I'm using this code

```
Weekstart = DATEDD(Wk, DATEDIFF(d,0,CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),103)) / 7,0)
```

This above query is given me the output in this format '2022-02-07 00:00:00.000' however I want the date in this format '07-Feb-22'

Comment: Date formatting is *usually* done in the presentation layer (web app, PDF etc) not in the database

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. There's no if or but about it. Your expression will work only by chance in some locales, producing unexpected or invalid dates in all others. Formats apply only when dates are rendered into strings *by the clients*

Comment: The expression `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(),103))` would behave as `cast(GetDate() as date)` *at best*.

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO - NEVER use 2 digit years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to avoid:

- Shorthand like `Wk` and `d` - [this isn't code golf](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- Magic dates like `0` - again, not code golf
- Style `103` doesn't belong here at all, that is when you are taking a *string* in a regional format (which you also should avoid), not when converting a datetime to a date
- Lots more things to avoid here: [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

I would do it this way. Use a base date that you *know* falls on the same weekday that you consider the start of the week:

```
DECLARE @base date = '20180101';

SELECT Weekstart = REPLACE(CONVERT(char(9), 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, @base, GETDATE())/7, @base), 6),' ','-');
```

The only magic / shorthand in here is the style number, `6`, which is a very specific way to coerce a date/time into a specific format ([discover them all here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)). Some will suggest the built-in `FORMAT()` function, which matches capability in other languages like C#, but I suggest avoiding it. Not only is it not available in flavors of SQL Server that don't support CLR or x64 (like Azure SQL Edge), the [overhead is substantial](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).